# how to handle nullable time stamp in protobuf file

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-core, grpc, protobuf-net

I Want to define nullable `timestamp` in my `protobuf` file but I can't find way to define it.

I tried to find right property type for nullable `timestamp` but there is no item in `google/protobuf/wrappers.proto` to define `timestamp` as nullable.

Comment: See [Protobuf and Null Support](https://itnext.io/protobuf-and-null-support-1908a15311b6) for a good summary of the challenge and some solutions

Answer (score 0):

```
syntax = "proto3";

import "google/protobuf/timestamp.proto";
import "google/protobuf/struct.proto";
import "google/protobuf/wrappers.proto";

package YourPackageName.v1;

service YourService {
// your apis
}

message NullableTimeStamp {
    oneof ItemType
    {
        google.protobuf.NullValue null = 1;
        google.protobuf.Timestamp timestamp = 2;
    }
}
```